# Not able to destroy the scope value on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-chart

I have one chart Directive, where on click of bar I am emitting the value to the controller.

```
// on click of bar chart emitting distict name
function onSeriesClick(e) {
    scope.$emit('districtIdClicked', e.category);
    scope.$apply();

}
```

In controller.

```
// Passing values to map directive clicked District ID
$scope.clickedDistrictId = null;
console.log($scope.clickedDistrictId);
var lis = $scope.$on('districtIdClicked', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.clickedDistrictId = data;
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    lis();
});
```

Here I am listing his value and again I want to pass to the another directive. So I assign in one `scope` and hen I am watching this `scope` in another `directive`.

```
// functionality for If District is not in visible on map, it should zoom out to show the selected district. 
scope.$watch('clickedDistrictId', function (selectedDistrictID) {
    if (scope.districtBoundaryData !== undefined) {
        updateMapSetDistrictPolygon(voltageMap, scope.districtBoundaryData, selectedDistrictID);
    }
});
```

Problem is I am not able to destroy the value (until i will go to different page). If on click chart bar it is having same value, value is emitted to controller but not able to watch in another directive,

Is there any way to explicitly destroy the value of scope?

Comment: I would suggest to build a service in between, that holds all the states of your chart directive. When you click in your chart directive, don't fire an event, change a property in your model. In your controller you can then listen to that property. This also provides a clean difference of who is responsible for what (directive for UI stuff, model for the intern logic), and is easy to unit test.